# Convert raster format to xyz format based on the coordinates we need

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

I interpolated a series of data in .xls format using ArcGIS, it converted the result to a raster format after interpolation. I need to extract data based on the lat and lon from this raster. How can I do it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try extract multivalues to points.